# Configure nginx to host a React app on VPS

Tags: nginx, vps

I have been following this tutorial to host my first React app on a VPS server: https://medium.com/swlh/react-app-deployment-to-vps-cloud-server-2de4387f59f4#56a7
Please bear with me, as this is the first time I am configuring a server of any kind. My server is a VPS with debian9 and the following specs, not sure if this is important:

```
RAM: 2GB
VCPU: 1 VCPU
Disc: 25GB
```

In the tutorial, I have gotten as far as cloning my app from my git repo and running the build on my server's ip:5000 port. SO I can now view my app online when I visit http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:5000/.

I am stuck at the nginx `default` file configuration part. The tutorial says that upon going to `cd /etc/nginx/sites-available` and doing `nano default` I should change the following in my `default` file, replacing the placeholder with my actual IP address:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default         upgrade;
    ''              close;
}
server {
     
       server_name YOUR_SERVER_PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS;
       
       location / {
        # Backend nodejs server
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_set_header    Upgrade     $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    Connection  $connection_upgrade;
    }
}
```

The problem is, that my NGINX default file looks completely different:

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
 # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#       listen 80;
#       listen [::]:80;
#
#       server_name example.com;
#
#       root /var/www/example.com;
#       index index.html;
#
#       location / {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#
```

Can someone please guide me how to porceed from here and how to update the default file so that it works in my scenario?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have missed this sentence in that tutorial:

> Now go to the end of "default" opened file and paste following code in.

**default** is the name of an existing configuration file created by Nginx. The command `nano default` will open that file. After opening, go to the end of the file, then append/paste the example code block. Don't forget to change `YOUR_SERVER_PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS` to your actual IP. Finally, save (CTRL+O) and close (CTRL+ X) the file.

The **default** file after editing will look like this:

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#       listen 80;
#       listen [::]:80;
#
#       server_name example.com;
#
#       root /var/www/example.com;
#       index index.html;
#
#       location / {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default         upgrade;
    ''              close;
}
server {
     
       server_name YOUR_SERVER_PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS;
       
       location / {
        # Backend nodejs server
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_set_header    Upgrade     $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    Connection  $connection_upgrade;
    }
}
```